# JavaScript prototype inheritance?

Tags: javascript

```
var pluginProto = m[0].prototype;
var cnds = pluginProto.cnds;
if (position_aces)
{
    cnds.CompareX = function (cmp, x)
    {
        return cr.do_cmp(this.x, cmp, x);
    };
}
```

I thought above code should inherit their values in a reverse way.

```
(define var cnds -> var pluginProto.cnds = cnd -> m[0]prototype = pluginProto)
```

and I am still wondering how above code can inherit their values to m[0]prototype without any problem.

What am I missing about prototype inheritance? Can a prototype reference any values without limitation of when the value was created?

Comment: "Methods" in JavaScript are just functions (executed in an obj.method form). The [[protochain]] only affects how properties (which can name functions) are resolved ..

Comment: Its hard to see what is going on here without a full example. In any case, you can't directly access the prototype of a Javascript object after it is created (you can only do it in firefox, via the nonstandard `__proto__` property)